# How Are We Sure That Channel Will Read The Whole Buffer Before Goroutine Closes It?

Tags: go, concurrency

I am reading of the book `Concurrency in Go`, in the book I saw a suggested design pattern, called lexical concurrency.

It is working like this:

```golang
chanOwner := func() <-chan int {
    results := make(chan int, 5)
    go func() {
        defer close(results)
        for i := 0; i <= 5; i++ {
            results <- i
        }
    }()
    return results
}

consumer := func(results <-chan int) {
    for result := range results {
        fmt.Printf("Received: %d\n", result)
    }
    fmt.Println("Done receiving!")
}

results := chanOwner()
consumer(results)
```

I know that a goroutine may invoke at any time in the future, so I don't understand how are we actually sure that results range will read all the buffer before goroutine actually closes the channel.

Comment: You can't, but it doesn't matter, the receiver still reads the buffered values.

Comment: To clarify Jim's comment: Closing a channel only indicates to consumers that there will be no new values sent to the channel (other than the ones already in the channel's buffer). However, even after the channel has been closed, consumers can continue to receive values from that channel.

Answer (score 1):

closing a channel only indicates that no new values will be sent to it. the values already in the channel are unaffected and can still be consumed.